# How to make group with repetition in regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching to extract coordinate from a text like this:

```
"xxxxxxx 453740N0093059E 453356N0093503E 
453225N0094201E 453238N0095044E 453351N0095543E 453618N0095826E 
453740N0093059 yyyyyyy 453351N0095543E 453740N0093059 
pppppppp 453740N0093059E 453740N0093059 nnnnnn 
nnnnnn 453618N0095826E 453740N0093059 453225N0094201E ...."
```

Where xxx, yyy, nnn and ppp can be any words.

Se I need to extract whatever find in the form [0-9]{6}N[0-9]{7}E and create group of consecutive coordinates so that I can obtain:

```
1: 453740N0093059E 453356N0093503E 453225N0094201E 453238N0095044E 453351N0095543E 453618N0095826E 453740N0093059 
2: 453351N0095543E 453740N0093059 
3: 453740N0093059E 453740N0093059 
4: 453618N0095826E 453740N0093059 453225N0094201E ....
5: ...
...
```

Without knowing how many coordinate groups are present.

I've tried to implement regex

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{6}N[0-9]{7}E\s([0-9]{6}N[0-9]{7}E)*?/",$text,$res)
```

But it gives back Array with only one coordinate every index, and not a group of consecutive coordinates.

Thank you

Comment: Try `preg_match_all` with `'~\d{6}N\d{7}E(?:\s+\d{6}N\d{7}E?)*~'` or more precise ``'~(?<!\S)\d{6}N\d{7}E(?:\s+\d{6}N\d{7}E?)*(?!\S)~'``, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKa1vR/1).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/gKa1vR/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `E` seems to be optional in your pattern, you need to quantify it with `?`.

Next, you grouped the `[0-9]{6}N[0-9]{7}E` part leaving `\s` outside and that already prevents the regex from even trying to match consecutive whitespace separated subpatterns. You need to use `(?:\s[0-9]{6}N[0-9]{7}E?)*` to match 0 or more sequences of a whitespace followed with the coordinate.

Use

```
preg_match_all('~(?<!\S)\d{6}N\d{7}E(?:\s\d{6}N\d{7}E?)*(?!\S)~', $s, $matches)
```

Or, if there can be more than 1 whitespace between the coordinates

```
preg_match_all('~(?<!\S)\d{6}N\d{7}E(?:\s+\d{6}N\d{7}E?)*(?!\S)~', $s, $matches)
                                         ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4oUwAB/1). Note `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` will ensure a match only inside whitespaces or at the start/end of string. Remove if you do not need to check this condition.

Note you may need to first shrink-&-normalize all whitespace in the string, then use

```
$re = '~(?<!\S)\d{6}N\d{7}E(?:\s+\d{6}N\d{7}E?)*(?!\S)~';
$s = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $s);
if (preg_match_all($re, $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/WUP2n).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. 

About `E` it was my fault using copy and past.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write some simple expressions and connect them using logical ORs for various cases that you might have, such as:

```
\b([0-9]{6}[NSWE]{1,2}[0-9]{7}[NSWE]{1,2})\b|\b([0-9]{6}[NSWE]{1,2}[0-9]{7})\b
```

not sure though.

#### Test

```
$re = '/\b([0-9]{6}[NSWE]{1,2}[0-9]{7}[NSWE]{1,2})\b|\b([0-9]{6}[NSWE]{1,2}[0-9]{7})\b/s';
$str = 'xxxxxxx 453740N0093059E 453356N0093503E
453225N0094201E 453238N0095044E 453351N0095543E 453618N0095826E
453740N0093059 yyyyyyy 453351N0095543E 453740N0093059
pppppppp 453740N0093059E 453740N0093059 nnnnnn
nnnnnn 453618N0095826E 453740N0093059 453225N0094201E ....';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$output = [];
$output["groups"] = [];
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[2]) {
        $output["groups"][2][$key] = $value[2];
    } else if ($value[1]) {
        $output["groups"][1][$key] = $value[1];
    } else {
        // The expression can be modified and
        // Other cases can be added here
        continue;
    }
}

var_dump($output["groups"]);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "453740N0093059E"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "453356N0093503E"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "453225N0094201E"
    [3]=>
    string(15) "453238N0095044E"
    [4]=>
    string(15) "453351N0095543E"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "453618N0095826E"
    [7]=>
    string(15) "453351N0095543E"
    [9]=>
    string(15) "453740N0093059E"
    [11]=>
    string(15) "453618N0095826E"
    [13]=>
    string(15) "453225N0094201E"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [6]=>
    string(14) "453740N0093059"
    [8]=>
    string(14) "453740N0093059"
    [10]=>
    string(14) "453740N0093059"
    [12]=>
    string(14) "453740N0093059"
  }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mFfyEI/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/mFfyEI/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]